# SQL server Delete script order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My tables have the following relations

[image]

As you can see `FirstEntity` can have multiple `Transactions` related record. `Transaction` is divided into two tables because it represents an inheritance hierarchy (Table Per Type in Entity Framework).

I need to create a script which delete all record from `FirstEntityTransaction` and `Transaction` given a `FirstEntityID`. The delete should then follow the following order:

- Delete all records from `FirstEntityTransaction`
- Delete all records from `Transaction`
- Delete record from `FirstEntity`

The problem is that when I execute first delete (`FirstEntityTransaction`) I do not have any way to find the related transactions by TransactionID. Is there any way that I can save those IDs and then execute the second delete?

EDIT: I have modified the post to have a more meaningful diagram

Comment: Do you use code first?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Right. But the delete script should be made offline by using pure SQL.

Comment: Why don't you start deletions by `Transaction` table? If `FirstEntityTransaction` is the parent table of `Transaction`, then you have to start deletions by `Transaction` table due to `FK` restrictions anyway.

Comment: Junction tables usually used by many to many relation. Isn't this more suitable for your case? `class FirstEntity {public int FirstEntityID{get;set;} public virtual ICollection<EntityTransaction>{get;set;}} class EntityColletion{public int Id{get;set;} public EntityTypeEnum Type{get;set;}`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos: because there is a foreign key between `FirstEntityTransaction` and `Transaction` like the following :`ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FirstEntityTransaction]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.FirstEntityTransaction_dbo.Transaction_TransactionID] FOREIGN KEY([TransactionID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Transaction] ([TransactionID])`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: It seems to me that the way you suggest is `Table-Per-Hierarchy` which I can not change at the moment. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, I think it is not TPH. You can have TPT but just one table for all transactions.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Ok. Good to know. However I can not change the design at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is an example that inserts deleted entity transactions into a table variable, which is subsequently used to delete the Transaction rows.

```
DECLARE @DeletedMyEntityTransaction table ( TransactionID int );

DELETE  dbo.MyEntityTransaction
OUTPUT  deleted.TransactionID
        INTO @DeletedMyEntityTransaction
WHERE   MyEntityID = @MyEntityID;

DELETE  dbo.[Transaction]
WHERE   TransactionID IN ( SELECT   TransactionID
                           FROM     @DeletedMyEntityTransaction );

DELETE  dbo.MyEntity
WHERE   MyEntityID = @MyEntityID;
```

Comment: Wow. This should work in my case. I did'nt realized I can use a temp Table. Do I need to delete the temp table at the end?

Comment: @Lorenzo Dan is using a table *variable*. It is implicitly deallocated as soon as it goes out of scope.

Comment: @Lorenzo Also, you can have indexes on table variable. I suggest, depend on nature of your table, to use JOIN instead of IN.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, table variables can have primary keys and/or unique constraints which are implemented by indexes in SQL Server, but not non-unique indexes.  One could add MyEntityID to the table variable, declare a composite primary key on TransactionID and EntityID on the variable, and add EntityID to the OUTPUT clause.  Whether or not that will improve performance (or a regular temp table with just Transaction and a non-unique index on Transaction) is something Lorenzo will need to test.

Comment: @DanGuzman - True in this case as the OP is on 2012 but 2014+ support non unique indexes.